# Registering ConfigSection with autofac does not work

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to register a settings object, `MySettings` with AutoFac but when calling a constructor with said settings all the properties have default values.

The settings in my project (`Appsettings/appsettings.json`)

```
{
    "MySettings": {
        "RequestTimeout": "00:00:20"
    }
}
```

The definition of `MySettingsConfig`:

```
public class MySettingsConfig
{
    public TimeSpan RequestTimeout { get; set; }
}
```

The code that registers the settings:

```
var mySettingsConfig = new MySettingsConfig();
config.TryGetConfigSection(nameof(BerichtModuleResilienceConfig)).Bind(mySettingsConfig);
builder.RegisterInstance<MySettingsConfig>(mySettingsConfig ).SingleInstance();
```

But when a class is created with the settings object in the constructor contains default values:

```
public MyClass(IOptions<MySettingsConfig> mySettings)
{
     //mySettings.RequestTimeout == "00:00:00"
}
```

I have tried multiple ways to register these settings and checked where the appsettings.json file is copied on build. What else could I be missing?

Comment: This would probably be good to work out without Autofac in the mix. Try writing the code without DI and make sure it works that way first. Autofac isn't magic and isn't a configuration system.

Answer (score 0):

You appsettings json has structure:

```
{
    "MySettings": {
        "RequestTimeout": "00:00:20"
    }
}
```

It is actually equivalent to:

```
class Configuration
{
  public Settings MySettings {get;set;}
}

class Settings{
   public TimeSpan RequestTimeout {get;set}
}
```

So try this structure instead of yours as well